# How to ggregate every column of a dataframe except for two

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe `df` which has some very large number of columns. Say one of those columns is named `year`, another is named `col1`, and another is named `col2`. If I am aggregating by `year`, how can I aggregate every column of `df` *except* `col1` and `col2` in one line of code using `aggregate()` (I wish to exclude `col1` and `col2` from the resulting data frame)? Can I use `.` notation to do this?

```
aggregate(. - col1 - col2 ~ year , data = df, FUN = mean, na.action= na.pass)
```

Something like the above line of code obviously doesn't work, but it may help illuminate what I mean. I want to somehow exclude `col1` and `col2` from the left hand side of `~` while still using `.` to capture all of the other variables (since there are many of them). Is this possible? I realize it may be more effective to simply remove these two variables from `df` before aggregating, but is there a way to achieve this result in just one line of code using only `aggregate()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(.~year, data=df[,colnames(df)[!colnames(df) %in% c("col1","col2")]], FUN=mean)
```

or data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD, mean,na.rm=T),by=year,.SDcols=!c("col1","col2")]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` option would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   summarise(across(-c(col1, col2), mean, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

With `aggregate`, we may also use `subset` with `select` option

```
aggregate(. ~ year, data = subset(df, select = -c(col1, col2)), 
     FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```